# rescheduling created thread and stop it after fixed delay

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am facing one problem regarding rescheduling existing thread.Basically I want to create a new thread with some identifier in a function call and stop it after some specified period of time lets say 5 min.now two case will happen

1. if same function called again with same identifier within 5 min in that case thread have to reschedule its stop time again for 5 more min from current time.
2. if same function called again with same identifier after 5 min in that case new thread will create which will stop after 5 min.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

This is close to being too broad, but here is a simple recipe how to approach such problems:

- you create a holder for a timestamp which can be read and written in a thread-safe manner
- when that new thread starts, it simply writes the current time into that holder
- when the function is called while the thread is still running, that "other" code simply updates the timestamp to the current time
- that thread should be checking the timestamp regularly - and when the thread finds "now >= timestamp + 5 min) - you know that the 5 minutes are over and the thread can stop.

Answer (score 0):

i got my answer.what i have done is basically created a map which can store string as key and ScheduledFuture object as value. i used executor.schedule() method to create thread with delay of 5 min. within update method thread will be checked in map whether it exist or not. And if not available in that case method will create new thread with 5 min of delay and add it to betamap object . if update method called within 5 minutes with same thread name in that case thread will be canceled by calling t.cancel(false) and create a new thread with 5 min of delay and store it in betamap. After 5 minutes run method will be called and thread will stop automatically.but in run method i need to delete current executing thread from map.
I don't know the way i explained is understood by you guys or not but i will put code below which may be helpful to understand.

### code what i have done

public class BetaUserServiceImpl{

```
    public static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(15); 

        static ScheduledFuture<?> t,t1;

        public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> betaMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        int timeDelay = 5;

        public void update(String threadname)
        {

        synchronized (betaMap) {

        if (betaMap.containsKey(threadname))
            {

        t = betaMap.get(threadname);

        t.cancel(false);

        Iterator it = betaMap.entrySet().iterator();

            while (it.hasNext())
             {

               Entry item = (Entry) it.next();

                if(item.getKey().equals(threadname))
                {
                   betaMap.remove(item.getKey());   
               }
            }
            t1=executor.schedule(new BetaUserThreadSchedular("thread1"), 
            timeDelay,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            betaMap.put(threadname, t1);
        }
        else
         {
        t=executor.schedule(new BetaUserThreadSchedular(threadname),timeDelay,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        betaMap.put(threadname, t);
        }
        }
        }
```

}

### Thread class

public class BetaUserThreadSchedular implements Runnable {

```
private Thread thread;
private String deviceId;

 public BetaUserThreadSchedular(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

public void run() {

    synchronized (BetaUserServiceImpl.betaMap) {
        try {

             Iterator it = BetaUserServiceImpl.betaMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext())
                {
                   Entry item = (Entry) it.next();
                   if(item.getKey().equals(deviceId)  )
                   {

                       BetaUserServiceImpl.betaMap.remove(item.getKey());   
                   }
                }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e);
        }   
    }
}

public void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
```

}